# Backbone.js Modifying data in model before save

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I was wondering how I would go about converting data when I call the `set` or `save` methods on a model. Specifically converting the inputted date string to epoch time.

I know I could just convert it in the view, but as far as I know, that wont work very well with my validations.

The model code is [here](https://github.com/tominated/vendotron/blob/master/src/app/models/receipt.js) if you are interested.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: btw you test for the amount to be blank twice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I can gather you have two options:

#### 1 Convert them in your view

This means you can roll your own conversions for the view or use something like Backbone.modelbinder to make the conversions for you. Then you have to modify your validate method to accept an epoch date. Personally I would prefer this one, I think that it's suitable for the UI to handle verifying user input's well-formedness and conversion to the right unit and let the model handle validating if the values are within the accepted limits.

#### 2 Convert them in your model

Backbone doesn't offer this out-of-the-box. If you set something to be something, there is no easy way to convert it to something else, especially between `validate` and `set`. Basically your best bet would be to roll your own `set` -function with something like

```
// Inside the set function
...
if (!this._validate(attrs, options)) return false; // real line in the set func
// insert something like this, after validate you know the values are eligible for conversion
attrs = this.convert(attrs); // a custom func that converts attributes to right units
...
// set continues as usual
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks jakee. Your answer seems like the most appropriate solution. I've since decided to re-factor the process and I'm doing away with the need to re-format any attributes though

Comment: you could also probably do something when the change:attribute event fires, which is fired by set and save (if you pass the attribute to it)

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the sync method in your model:

```
, sync: function(method, model) {
    if(method === 'update'){
        // change you model here
    }
}
```

This will be invoke bevor data is send to the backend server. The "method" indecates 'create' or 'update'.

Comment: This is the recommended approach by Backbone itself. See http://backbonejs.org/#Sync & http://backbonejs.org/#Model-sync

Answer (score -1):

According to the sources, validate is the only callback that is called before set and save. <strike>You can to set the values in your validate method directly on the attributes object.</strike> Unfortunately you cannot make any changes to attributes at this point.

You can use a plugin like [backbone.getters.setters](https://github.com/berzniz/backbone.getters.setters) to do this since it looks like it [won't be a feature](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/1043) added to backbone.

Comment: It seems that backbone makes a copy of the attributes object for the validation method from what I can gather in the sources and my testing, so that won't work unfortunately.

Comment: `attrs = _.extend({}, this.attributes, attrs);` straight up quote from source, so no modifying the attributes object inside `validate`

Comment: @jakee that is the set of attributes that get passed to the validate method. You still have access to this.attributes and you can still change those. Tom, have you tried modifying this.attributes rather than those passed to as parameters to validate?

Comment: @TanzeebKhalili I have and it appears that it doesn't work (or I'm doing something wrong)

Comment: well it won't work that way because the attributes will be set AFTER the validation so set during validation to be what you want -> they are set to the original values passed to set afterwards

Comment: Very good point, my method definitely won't work. Answer updated.